# What song plays when Cade is fixing the painting robot in "Transformers: Age of Extinction"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, music-identification, transformers-age-of-extinction

In the fourth *Transformers* movie, there's a track playing in the background when Cade is fixing the painting robot (when Tessa brings him his dinner). It's at about 21 minutes and 40 seconds into the movie.

Does anyone know what the title of the song is, or who it's by? It's not on the soundtrack.

Comment: It just sounds like incidental music to me.

Comment: I really get the feeling it's a version of *Tessa* or *Best Thing That Ever Happened* that was slightly altered or mixed differently in post. It bears a lot of similarities, but with more prominent drums.

Comment: Who could I get in touch with to try and find out?

Comment: Phantom power did a lot of the trailer music for TF4, have you checked their [website](http://www.phantompowerblog.com/)? Might get lucky and it was left over trailer music used in the movie. I don't have a copy of TF4 yet so can't listen to the scene.

Comment: If it’s not [The Touch](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90006/in-universe-was-eddie-and-reed-s-song-the-touch-plagiarised-by-transformers-a) they really missed a trick.

Answer (score 2):

It is [**"Painter Bot Broken"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2ZqTCGTB70) by **Steve Jablonsky**, from ["Transformers Age Of Extinction – 2 X CD Complete Score – Special Edition – Steve Jablonsky"](https://elitesoundtracks.com/products/transformers-age-of-extinction-complete-score-special-edition-steve-jablonsky-2/)

[**+ movie scene in question (youtube)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CTcVNgtV2U&t=126s)

[image]